# Translation of real value into complex-value integral equivalent

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove that for all $\xi \in \mathbb{C}$, we have:

$$e^{-\pi \xi^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^2}e^{2\pi i x \xi}dx $$

Quite frankly, I'm a bit baffled at how to start... should I be trying to represent the right hand side as integrals over three curves? (curves which make up a half circle?)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: This cannot be true. E.g. $\xi =0$ would give a contradiction.

Comment: there is probably a $e^{-\pi x^2}$ missing in the RHS's integral.

Comment: Sorry, @mookid is right! Edited OP.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to notice that both sides solve the (complex) initial value problem

$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll} u^\prime(\xi)=-2\pi \xi u(\xi) & \,\\
u(0)=1 & \,\end{array}\right.$$

Now conclude by uniqueness theory of that ODE.

Comment: Thanks, but this is from Stein's *Complex Analysis* -- not sure that this theorem is covered there... The problems surrounding the one in the OP involve translation of real-valued integrals into a series of integrals that sum to 0 (via Cauchy's theorem), so I think that's what they're trying to get at.

Comment: @Ryan Yu:  I'm inclined to agree with you still Your Ad Here's solution is nice, don't you think?

Comment: @RyanYu: Yes, there is also a contour integral version of this proof. To find the correct contour you need to make sure that the piece away from the real axis can be estimated to converge to zero, i.e. look at $|e^{-\pi\xi^2}e^{2\pi i x\xi}|$. This evaluates to $e^{bla}$ where $bla$ is a real quantity dep. on $\xi$ which should converge to $-\infty$ along the outward contour.

Comment: Okay, great. I'm a bit new to this -- would you recommend using a contour that is represented by two curves, one that lies on the real axis and one that is the boundary of a half circle?

Comment: @RyanYu: Try a rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

You can also expand the series:

$$
\int e^{-\pi x^2} e^{2i\pi x\xi} dx =
\int e^{-\pi x^2} \sum (2i\pi x\xi)^n/n! dx 
\\
= \sum (2i\pi \xi)^{2n}/(2n)! \int e^{-\pi x^2} x^{2n} dx
\\
= \sum (2i\pi \xi)^{2n} \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 1}{(2\pi)^n(2n)!}
\\
=  \sum (-4 \pi\xi^2)^{n} \frac{1}{2^{2n}n!}
\\
=\sum (-\pi \xi^2)^{n} \frac{1}{n!}
= \exp -\pi\xi^2$$

Comment: Nice. You lost some constants somewhere, though. Your third equality is by writing $e^{-\pi x^2}x\cdot x^{2n-1}$ and integrating by parts, I assume? This is also where you dropped a factor $\pi$.

Comment: yes. It also uses the fact that $\int e^{-\pi x^2} = 1$, a convenient definition of $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, but in the end you have a $\pi^2$ instead of $\pi$.

Comment: I made corrections. There was a problem with the IPP

Comment: Thanks. Followup -- how did you get from the first line to the second line?

Comment: Using the Fubini theorem, and the parity of the x-> exp(ax^2) function.